# I want to make Carousel responsive with angular, how to do it?

Tags: html, angular, carousel

HTML:

```html
 <div class="voxel-row">
            <div class="voxel-col-4"><h2 id="vagas_recentes">vagas recentes</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">        
                    <div class="row">
                        <div *ngFor="let item of vagas" (click)="openJobPage(item.code)"  class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="card vaga_card_home">
                                <div class="card-img-top card_vagas_title card_vagas_header">
                                    <voxel-icon *ngIf="item.voxelIcon">{{item.voxelIcon}}</voxel-icon>
                                    <voxel-icon *ngIf="!item.voxelIcon">inovacao_outline</voxel-icon>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="card_vagas_title">
                                        <h3>{{ (item.name.length>40)? (item.name | slice:0:40)+'...':(item.name) }}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card_vagas_bottom">
                                        <p>{{item.addressState}} - {{item.addressCity}}</p>
                                        <div class="orange_subline"></div>
                                        <p *ngIf="item.daysSinceUpdated > 0">Há {{item.daysSinceUpdated}} dia(s)<br>Expira em {{item.dataExpiracao | date :
                                            'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
                                        <p *ngIf="item.daysSinceUpdated == 0">Publicada hoje<br>Expira em {{item.dataExpiracao | date :
                                            'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
this.vagaService.obterVagasHome('recent').subscribe(
  (response: VagaResponseModel) => {
    try {
      this.vagas = response.results;

      let vagasToShow: any[] = [];

      if (this.deviceService.isMobile() && this.vagas) {
        vagasToShow = this.vagas.slice(0, 2);
      } else if (this.deviceService.isTablet() && this.vagas) {
        vagasToShow = this.vagas.slice(0, 3);
      } else if (this.deviceService.isDesktop() && this.vagas) {
        vagasToShow = this.vagas.slice(0, 4);
      }

      this.vagas = vagasToShow;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log((e as Error).message);
    }

    this.loadingService.hide();
    this.shimmer = false;
  },
  (error: any) => {
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 500) {
      this.loadingService.hide();
      return;
    }

    this.loadingService.hide();
    return;
  }
);
```

I want 1 job card to appear when on mobile screens, 3 cards on tablet screens, and 4 cards on desktop screens. How to do this?

With this code I posted above, it is only recognizing the first if:

```
  if (this.deviceService.isMobile() && this.vacancies) {
         jobsToShow = this.jobs.slice(0, 2);
```

and showing 2 cards on the screen for any screen size and not considering the rest of else conditions

Comment: What is `deviceService`? It's probably that which is not working.

Comment: Or you could use flex boxes and set the width using percentages according to the device. It will also be useful if you share your scss file, maybe you are blocking the expected behavior with another style in your component.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your src/index.html file and add Bootstrap CSS `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">` then add the following class to the elements you want affected `class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3"`

**Unless you don't want bootstrap**